# mantener div en posicion

Tags: javascript, css

he creado un div con forma triangular y fondo transparente y quiero hacerlo responsive, me refiero a que le he dado una posición absoluta y cuando disminuyo el tamaño de la pantalla se desplaza hacia abajo. He visto una manera de hacerlo que es crear estilo dentro del div a través de JS, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. La muestra de refenecia es esta página web https://joincoup.com/es/madrid. Es el div con id #mask inferior de la cabecera.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Gracias de antemano

```css
#hero {

 position: relative;
}

 #mask {

  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 230px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 230px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1920px solid white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 25;
  pointer-events: none;

 }


#cabecera {

 background-color: red;
 height: 130vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
 z-index: 1;
 
}



.text {
 
  position: absolute; 
   bottom: 40%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
   list-style: none;
   border-bottom: 0;
   font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif; 
}

.linea-lateral::before {

 left: 0;

}

.linea-lateral::before, .linea-lateral::after {

 border-bottom: 0.1em solid white;
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: 2em;

}


.linea-lateral::after {

 right: 0;
}



 .box p {

  font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
 
 }
```

```html
<section id="hero">

        <div id="cabecera">

                <div class="box">

                          <h1>paula domingo</h1>


             


                </div>
                
        </div>
          
        <div id="mask"></div>

      </section>
```

Comment: Con `media queries de CSS` puedes solucionarlo

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero creo que tendría que reflejar infinitos media queries. Creo que se trata de una fórmula que detecte el ancho de la ventana, mediante $(window).width() y aplicar la fórmula para que introduzca un style al div y la progresión por cada pixel que disminuya el tamaño, pixel que decrece el tamaño del triángulo y la posición.

Comment: tambien puede ser, la función `resize` de `javascript` es muy potente

Comment: OK, lo voy a mirar.

Comment: Hola, puedes colocar una url valida de tu background ya que al ejecutarlo se ve en blanco y no se puede trabajar en una respuesta precisa

Comment: Lo he puesto con background red para que se pueda ver.

Comment: Y he modificado el top para que veas que le pasa a mi triángulo cuando se hace el display en dispositivos con diferentes tamaños. ese triangulo se tiene que quedar justo al fondo de la cabecera, para hacer un div truncado.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías utilizar media queries, te dejo las de los diferentes tipos de dispositivos, SOLO CREA 3 CLASES (.web-styles, .tablet-styles, .mobile-styles) Y YA NO HACES INFINITOS MEDIA QUERIES:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .example {background: red;}
}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .example {background: green;}
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .example {background: blue;}
} 

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .example {background: orange;}
} 

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .example {background: pink;}
}
```

*Creo que si lo vemos desde la parte practica y teórica, seria mas sano hacerlo mediante CSS que con JS.*

Saludos.

Comment: Me queda la duda: ¿Cómo aplicarías tu respuesta para solucionar la pregunta del OP?

Comment: Crear 3 clases (.web-styles, .tablet-styles, .mobile-styles), metes tus estilos dentro del media query y a los tags HTML les agregas su CLASS.

Comment: En referencia a la repuesta de Ricardo, tan sólo con probarlo en el Samsung S5 y el S9 ya se me va...media queries para posiciones absolutas en la vertical creo que no es la respuesta. Me refiero cuando hay que hilar muy fino--> cuestión de un pixel.

Comment: Bueno, nos ilustras cuando lo soluciones vale? :) Saludos!

Comment: Sí a ver si doy con ello.